# Variable does not increment in PHP script

Tags: php

First: This is not a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042681/deprecated-session-is-register-error-php).  Same script, but different question.

I had initially thought the error in my previous question would have solved this error, but it didn't.

I'm making a simple 3-question quiz via PHP. The quiz runs without syntax errors, however the problem is that my variable $correct does not seem to increment throughout the quiz (given a correct answer).  I put print statements to see if it changes but nothing gets printed.  Somehow its not properly incrementing the value of the variable.

Instead of outputting:

```
 You got 2 out of 3 correct. //where 2 is the value of $correct
```

It outputs:

```
You got correct out of correct. //where the value $correct seems to have no value
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?php
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',900);
//echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"); 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}

 if(isset($_SESSION["blah"]))
{
$_SESSION["number"] = 0;
$_SESSION["correct"] = 0;
}

$total_number = 3;

print <<<TOP
<html>
<head>
<title> History Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> History Quiz </h3>
TOP;

$number = $_SESSION["number"];
$correct = $_SESSION["correct"];


if ($number == 0){
print <<<FIRST
<p> You will be given $total_number questions in this quiz. <br /><br/>
  You will have 15 minutes to complete it. <br /><br/>
  You cannot go back to change previous answers.<br /><br/>
  Here is your first question: <br /><br />
</p>
<p>1. Abe Lincoln was born in Illinois.</p>
<p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="true" /> True </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="false" /> False </label>
</p>
FIRST;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$selected_radio = $_POST['question1'];

if ($selected_radio == 'false') {
   $correct++;
print $correct;
   $_SESSION["correct"] = $correct;

}
}
}


if ($number == 1){
print <<<SECOND
<p>2. In what state was the battle of Gettysburg fought?</p>
<p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question2" value="Texas" /> a) Texas  
</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question2" value="Pennsylvania" /> b)  
Pennsylvania </label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question2" value="Virginia" /> c) Virginia   
</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question2" value="West Virginia" /> d) West   
Virginia </label>
</p>
SECOND;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(isset($_POST['question2']) &&
$_POST['question'] == 'Pennsylvania')
{
   $correct++;
   $_SESSION["correct"] = $correct;  
}

}
}


if ($number == 2){
print <<<THIRD
<p>3. The last name of the commander of the Army of North Virginia was __________.</p>
<p>
    <input type='text' id='question3' />
THIRD;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$selected_answer = $_POST['question3'];

if ($selected_answer == "lee") {
   $correct++;
   $_SESSION["correct"] = $correct;
 }
 }
 }


if ($number >= $total_number)
{
print <<<FINAL_SCORE
Your final score is $correct correct out of $total_number. <br /><br />
Thank you for playing. <br /><br />
FINAL_SCORE;
session_destroy();
}
else
{
$number++;
$_SESSION["number"] = $number;
$script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
print <<<FORM
<form method = "post" action = $script>
<input type = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
</form>
FORM;
}

?>
```

Julio, my current code (2nd Update):

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',900);
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["correct"])){
$correct = $_SESSION["correct"];
} else {
$number = 0;
$correct = 0;
}

// check if which question was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// set $number = the question that was submitted
$number = $_POST['question'];
switch ($_POST['question']){
    case 1:
        if ($_POST['answer']) $correct++; // this answer should be 'true'
        break;
    case 2:
        if ($_POST['answer'] == 2) $correct++; // this answer should be 'PA'
        break;
    case 3:
    if ($_POST['answer'] == "lee") $correct++; //this answer should be 'lee'
}
}   

// set the session correct var to our current tally
$_SESSION['correct'] = $correct;



$total_number = 3;

print <<<TOP
<html>
<head>
<title> History Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> History Quiz </h3>
TOP;

if ($number == 0){
print <<<FIRST
<p> You will be given $total_number questions in this quiz. <br /><br/>
  You will have 15 minutes to complete it. <br /><br/>
  You cannot go back to change previous answers.<br /><br/>
  Here is your first question: <br /><br />
</p>
<p>1. Abe Lincoln was born in Illinois.</p>
<p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="true" /> True </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="false" /> False </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="1" />
</p>
FIRST;
}


if ($number == 1){
print <<<SECOND
<p>2. In what state was the battle of Gettysburg fought?</p>
<p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="1" /> a) Texas  
</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="2" /> b)  
Pennsylvania </label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="3" /> c) Virginia   
</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="4" /> d) West   
Virginia </label>
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="2" />
</p>
SECOND;
}
if ($number == 2){
print <<<THIRD
 <p>3. The last name of the commander of the Army of North Virginia was __________.</p>
 <p>
    <input type='text' id='answer' />
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="3" />
 </p>
THIRD;
}

if ($number >= $total_number)
{
print <<<FINAL_SCORE
Your final score is $correct correct out of $total_number. <br /><br />
Thank you for playing. <br /><br />
FINAL_SCORE;
session_destroy();
}
else {
 $number++;
 $_SESSION['number'] = $number;
 $script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 print <<<FORM
<form method = "post" action = $script>
<input type = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
</form>
FORM;
}


?>
```

Comment: What if you use `$_SESSION["correct"]` when printing the final score?

Comment: I'm new to PHP so forgive me, but would my line look like this? -->Your final score is $_SESSION["correct"] correct out of $total_number.  <-- If so, I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick read of the code it looks like you're refreshing the page by posting to itself-- that means you're resetting the `$correct` variable to 0 each time. If you want to increment `$correct`, increment the value in the SESSION, then read out the session `$correct` value into the page's `$correct` var so it isn't reset on each form submit.

EDIT TO ADD SOME SAMPLE CODE:

```
<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["correct"])){
    $correct    = $_SESSION["correct"];
} else {
    $number     = 0;
    $correct    = 0;
}

// check if which question was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // set $number = the question that was submitted
    $number = $_POST['question'];
    switch ($_POST['question']){ //<-----replace this line
        case 1:
            if ($_POST['answer']) $correct++; // this answer should be 'true'
            break;
        case 2:
            if ($_POST['answer'] == 2) $correct++; // this answer should be 'PA'
            break;
        //etc.
    }
}   

// set the session correct var to our current tally
$_SESSION['correct'] = $correct;



$total_number = 3;

print <<<TOP
<html>
<head>
<title> History Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> History Quiz </h3>
TOP;

if ($number == 0){
    print <<<FIRST
    <p> You will be given $total_number questions in this quiz. <br /><br/>
      You will have 15 minutes to complete it. <br /><br/>
      You cannot go back to change previous answers.<br /><br/>
      Here is your first question: <br /><br />
    </p>
    <p>1. Abe Lincoln was born in Illinois.</p>
    <p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="true" /> True </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="false" /> False </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="question" value="1" />
    </p>
    FIRST;
}


if ($number == 1){
print <<<SECOND
<p>2. In what state was the battle of Gettysburg fought?</p>
<p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="1" /> a) Texas  
</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="2" /> b)  
Pennsylvania </label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="3" /> c) Virginia   
</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="4" /> d) West   
Virginia </label>
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="2" />
</p>
SECOND;
etc. . .
```

Comment: So if the answer is correct, I should have this: $_SESSION["correct"]++; ? When I print the final score I should do this: $_SESSION["correct"] = $correct;.  Is this what you mean?  Should I be deleting anything?

Comment: probably more like `$session++;` then `$_SESSION['correct'] = $session` before submit. Then at the head of the file, when you set the value for the initial $session, you can do something like `$session = isset($_SESSIONS['correct']) ? $_SESSION['correct'] : 0;`

Comment: Please see my question above -- I added stuff at the end.  Is that code what you mean?

Comment: Thanks so much for your example code!!  I went through it and added the last question, however when I try to run this, I get the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in line 20.... Line 20 is switch $_POST['question']{

Comment: I hacked this real quick and didn't run it-- it's sort of psuedo code, so I don't guarantee it's going to work, just that it should give you an idea. I've fixed the error above however.

Comment: Your code has been of great help!  I went through and added some things to it.  I do have question in regards to the submit button: where exactly do I put it?  Do I keep it where it was before after the if ($number >= $total_number) statement?  Also, do I keep still increment the $number variable?  See my recent code above.  It runs without error, but there is no action when the submit button is pressed.  Again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you've created another form for the submit-- you should start the form at the top of the scripted part, then do your `if/then` stuff, which will print out the appropriate inputs as needed, then add your `submit` before you close the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your first few lines at the top...

```
if(isset($_SESSION["blah"]))
{
  $_SESSION["number"] = 0;
  $_SESSION["correct"] = 0;
}
```

this means that $_SESSION['correct'] will only have a value if the $_SESSION['blah'] variable is set to begin with.  This could be your issue because if $_SESSION['correct'] doesn't have a value, none of the increments and assignment into $session won't work further down.

Comment: Makes sense.  How should I modify this?

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the

```
if(isset($_SESSION["blah"]))
{
  $_SESSION["number"] = 0;
  $_SESSION["correct"] = 0;
}
```

altogether as this would mean it is reset on page refresh.